# Fill heatmap missing values

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a two-variable table from which I want to make a heatmap.
Here's my code :

```
color <- read.table(textConnection("
Green Red 
0 0
0 1
1 1
0 2
0 5
0 1
0 0
0 0"), header = T)

tab <- table(color)
heatmap(tab, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

I would like to fill "missing" values by 0 on the heatmap, e.g. have horizontally 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (with 0's in the 3rd and 4th row) instead of 0, 1, 2, 5.

I've been unable to do it either automatically or manually by manipulating the contigency table generated ("tab").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the `factor` levels of `Green` and `Red` *prior* to constructing the table to include "empty" levels.

For example, let's say we want to consider levels `0..5` for `Green` and `0..2` for `Red`:

```
color$Red <- factor(color$Red, levels = as.character(0:5));
color$Green <- factor(color$Green, levels = as.character(0:2));

tab <- table(color);
```

Notice how `tab` now contains `0` entries for empty levels

```
tab;
#     Red
#Green 0 1 2 3 4 5
#    0 3 2 1 0 0 1
#    1 0 1 0 0 0 0
#    2 0 0 0 0 0 0

heatmap(tab, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

[image]

Since `heatmap` by default scales entries by row, it's a bit hard to see that missing levels really have `0` values, so let's switch off scaling:

```
heatmap(tab, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale = "none")
```

[image]

Here, red corresponds to `0`.